# UART port not getting accesed

Tags: beagleboneblack

i have activated UART2 in beaglebone black. i have enabled the UART 2 in /boot/uEnv.txt.

but cant communicate through the port.
 the result is as below

```
ls -l /dev/tty*


crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 62 Jan 28 14:17 /dev/tty62
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 63 Jan 28 14:17 /dev/tty63
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  7 Jan 28 14:17 /dev/tty7
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  8 Jan 28 14:17 /dev/tty8
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  9 Jan 28 14:17 /dev/tty9
crw--w---- 1 root tty     243,  0 Jan 28 14:17 /dev/ttyGS0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          5 Jan 28 14:17 /dev/ttyO0 -> ttyS0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          5 Jan 28 14:17 /dev/ttyO1 -> ttyS1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          5 Jan 28 14:17 /dev/ttyO2 -> ttyS2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          5 Jan 28 14:17 /dev/ttyO4 -> ttyS4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          5 Jan 28 14:17 /dev/ttyO5 -> ttyS5
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4, 64 Jan 28 14:17 /dev/ttyS0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout   4, 65 Jan 28 14:17 /dev/ttyS1
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout   4, 66 Jan 28 15:18 /dev/ttyS2
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout   4, 67 Jan 28 14:17 /dev/ttyS3
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout   4, 68 Jan 28 14:17 /dev/ttyS4
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout   4, 69 Jan 28 14:17 /dev/ttyS5
```

someone help

Answer (score 0):

I got it..
we have to add
config-pin P9_-- uart

-- represent the pin u want to make it